# Finding Prime Factors PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to loop through the entered number. Output all the number from 1 - number entered and change the color of the prime numbers to red. I can't seem to be able to come up with a good forloop to check for prime numbers.

```
             //Variables
            $number = $_POST['input'];
            $start = 1;

            while($start <= $number){
                if($start%10 == 1){
                print "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
            }

            $div_count = 0;
            for ($i=1;$i <= $number; $i++){
                if(($number%$i)==0){
                    $div_count++;
                }
            }
                if($div_count<3){
                    echo $number .",";
                    $start=$start+1;
                }
```

Comment: This may be a good application for the [prime sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 0):

```
$flag = 0;
    $no = 929;
    $var = $no/2;
    if($no == 1){
        echo "Not A prime and Composite ";
    }else{
        for($i=2;$i<=$var;$i++){
            if($no % $i == 0){
                $flag=1;
                echo"Prime";
                break;
            }
        }
        if($flag == 0){
            echo"prime";
        }
    }
```